# How Can i add a cloned object to the repository

Tags: typo3-9.x

New object is not cloned

```
$clonedObj = clone $repatNewsObj;
$this->extendednewsRepository->add($clonedObj);
$this->persistenceManager->persistAll();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not how you copy an extbase object with TYPO3. Sadly, just cloning it with PHP will not reset the object from the extbase point of view. The `add` method of the default repository will just ignore the "new" object if it already has a uid in the database. Hence, nothing is actually done by your persist call.

You could either create a new object yourself, setting each property manually, based on the source object or you can use the datahandler to copy your object. There is a [blog post](http://blog.marcdesign.ch/2015/05/27/typo3-extbase-objekte-kopieren/) describing it (in German) as well as an [older SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12463251/duplicating-extbase-repository-object) discussing the same issue.

If you want to clone an object from one of your own extensions, best practice is to overwrite the `__clone` method and reset things like `uid` and so on there. If the model class comes from a third party extension, chose one of the two methods from above.